# Mongoid: array contains any values of another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, mongodb, mongoid

I have a `Map` object with a 'cities' array field

```
class Map
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :cities, type: Array
end
```

I want to search for all the `Map` where at least one city is present from an other array. Something like this:

```
# map1.cities = ['London', 'Manchester']
# map2.cities = ['Paris', 'Lyon']
# map3.cities = ['Berlin', 'Munich']
# searchedCities = ['London', 'Paris']
```

I want all the maps that contains at least one of the searchedCities, in this case; map1 and map2.

This is not working, because it compares the whole array

```
Map.where(cities: searchedCities)
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Try `Map.any_in(cities: searched_cities)`

Comment: That's works great. Thanks a lot. I've probably missed that query in the documentation.

Comment: I will add it as an answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.any_in` (can't find a direct documentation) which generates a [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) mongodb query for you and it matches the document if the field contains any of the values from given array.

In your case:

```
Map.any_in(cities: searched_cities)
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"cities"=>{"$in"=>["London", "Paris"]}}
  ...
  class:    Map>
```